# How to pass an argument to a method decorator

Tags: python

I have a method decorator like this.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    class Decorator:
        def __init__(self, f):
            self.f = f
            self.msg = msg

        def __get__(self, instance, _):
            def wrapper(test):
                print(self.msg)
                print(instance.start)    
                self.f(instance, test)
                return self.f
            return wrapper

    @Decorator
    def p1(self, sent):
        print(sent)

c = MyClass()
c.p1('test')
```

This works fine. However, If I want to pass an argument to the decorator, the method is no longer passed as an argument, and I get this error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    class Decorator:
        def __init__(self, f, msg):
            self.f = f
            self.msg = msg

        def __get__(self, instance, _):
            def wrapper(test):
                print(self.msg)
                print(instance.start)    
                self.f(instance, test)
                return self.f
            return wrapper

    @Decorator(msg='p1')
    def p1(self, sent):
        print(sent)

    @Decorator(msg='p2')
    def p2(self, sent):
        print(sent)
```

How do I pass an argument to the decorator class, and why is it overriding the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The descriptor protocol doesn't serve much of a purpose here. You can simply pass the function itself to `__call__` and return the wrapper function without losing access to the instance:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    class Decorator:
        def __init__(self, msg):
            self.msg = msg

        def __call__(self, f):
            def wrapper(instance, *args, **kwargs):
                print(self.msg)
                # access any other instance attributes
                return f(instance, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper

    @Decorator(msg='p1')
    def p1(self, sent):
        print(sent)

>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.p1('test')
p1
test
```

Comment: I need the descriptor because I need to access the attributes of the instance of MyClass (not in my code). I've added a line to clarify.

Comment: I made mine a little bit clearer. You do have access to the instance here as well since it is always passed as an argument to the function anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is now the best solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

A decorator will be **called**.

In your case you receive the function as a parameter in the `__call__` method

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    class Decorator:
        def __init__(self, msg):
            self.msg = msg

        def __call__(self, f):
            self.f = f
            return self

        def __get__(self, instance, _):
            def wrapper(test):
                print(self.msg)
                self.f(instance, test)
                return self.f
            return wrapper

    @Decorator(msg='p1')
    def p1(self, sent):
        print(sent)

    @Decorator(msg='p2')
    def p2(self, sent):
        print(sent)
```

Your first example works because calling the `Class` creates an instance and the function is the parameter.

But in your second example you call the `Class` manually to set the `msg` parameter, so you the decoration process calls what's left, i.e.: the instance and that goes to the `__call__` method.

Comment: I get this error message though: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
when executing your code.

Comment: The `__call__` method needs to return `self` or the decorator syntax will replace the methods with `None` (which is obviously not going to be useful).

Answer (score 1):

When you call a decorator with arguments, the function you call isn't actually working as a decorator itself. Rather, it's a decorator factory (a function or other callable that `return`s something that will act as the decorator). Usually you solve this by adding an extra level of nested functions. Since you're defining your decorator with a class, that's a bit awkward to do directly (though you probably could make it work). But there doesn't really seem to be any need for your decorator to be a class, as long as you handle `self` in the wrapper function (it will be the `instance` of MyClass now, rather than an instance of a `Decorator` class):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0

    def decorator_factory(msg):
        def decorator(f):
            def wrapper(self, test): # you might want to replace test with *args and **kwargs
                print(msg)
                print(self.start)
                return f(self, test)
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    @decorator_factory(msg='p1')
    def p1(self, sent):
        print(sent)

    @decorator_factory(msg='p2')
    def p2(self, sent):
        print(sent)
```

I named the decorator factory the way I did to be explicit about the different levels of nested functions, but you should of course use something that's actually meaningful for your use case as the top level name. You might also want to move it out of the class namespace, since it will be available to call on all instances of `MyClass` (with possibly silly results, since it's not intended to be a method).